# How can I move things across dimensions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-factorization, minecraft-mystcraft

I have some barrels with *a lot* of stuff in them, and I need to move them to my new base in a different Mystcraft Age. I have already tried Portalguns from the Portalgun mod, but they seem to dislike Mystcraft. I could normally move barrels with the Gravity Gun, but I can't since portals don't work. How can I move my stuff **without** disassembling the barrels? This is using the FTB Direwolf20 pack.

Comment: I'm doing some science to figure out if this is possible, and I will get back to you. So far, it doesn't look promising.

Comment: You have only put down Factorization and Mystcraft but you are now listing other mods that you have installed. If this is for the FTB pack or what not its likely better to list that so we know if you have access to ender chests or the like to help out.

Comment: @James I added more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some testing using Mystcraft portals, constructed with crystals, I can conclude that it is not possible to carry barrels of stuff to different dimensions with the Gravity Gun; if I sent the barrel through the portal first, it appeared to have been deleted from the world. When I went through the portal first, the barrel fell from my grasp, and dropped a craftpacket stamper, deleting my stack of diamond blocks.

There are other ways to move items cross-dimensionally; Ender Chests and Item Tesseracts will happily transport your items to other places, as long as the other side is chunk loaded. A retriever with power and a timer will pull things out of the bottoms of barrels and put them in an ender chest with relative ease.

Comment: I should add make sure they are chunk loaded so no issues arise.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid disassembling the barrels unless you want to mess with external world editing tools to copy-paste your base across dimensions. You just have to do it the hard way.

Using a pair of Item Tesseracts (from Thermal Expansion) or Ender Chests, you can move items between worlds. Set up a piping system to withdraw from your barrels (a Retriever with an empty filter grid attached to pneumatic tubes attached to the bottom of the barrels) that feeds into your tesseract or chest. Use a Filter or a wooden transport pipe with a decent engine on the destination side to empty out the tesseract/chest into a waiting sorting/barrel system.

This requires duplication of your storage system and a chunkloader on either end, but if you've got that much stuff in barrels, you can spare the resources in the short term, and you can tear down and recover the original base's systems once they're empty.

I recommend a system with pneumatic tubes throughout – BC pipes are too liable to pop items out if you've miscalculated something. Tubes on the other hand will merely clog up, giving you opportunity to fix any throughput flaws without risking loss of items.

Answer (score 0):

you could possible use the q craft teleportation mechanics or the mffs mod mechanics and you should be able to do this without a problem.

P.S if you're going to use the mffs mod you will need a lot of steel